# Bitlocker on a device with three disks - what do I need to do before I can safely install Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, ssd

I want to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo T430. Right now I have 3 disks in the laptop.

- 240 GB SSD (Windows 10, Bitlocker enabled)
- 120 GB mSATA SSD (Empty, this is the one that i want to install Ubuntu)
- 2 TB HDD (Data drive, Bitlocker enabled)

Secure Boot is disabled, boot mode UEFI / No CSM

Do I need to decrypt Bitlocker on my Windows SSD drive before trying to install Ubuntu?

I do not want to decrypt it because, it said I need to unencrypt all devices that I encrypted before (it means 3 external, 1 internal drive)

Is there any risk for installation? I do not want to toss my Windows drive.

I do not need to reach the Windows SSD drive or 2 TB data drive.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to decrypt BitLocker on my Windows SSD drive before installing Ubuntu?

You don't need to decrypt BitLocker on your Windows SSD drive before installing Ubuntu.

> Is there any risk for installation?

Select the *Something else* option in the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer, and then install Ubuntu in the empty space of the 120 GB mSATA SSD. There is no risk for installation when you select the *Something else* option, as long as you are careful to select the 120 GB empty SSD and not the 240 GB which has Windows 10 installed on it.

[image: Something else]

Comment: In Windows PowerShell the Disable-Bitlocker command can be used to disable BitLocker Drive Encryption for a BitLocker volume: [Disable-BitLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/disable-bitlocker?view=winserver2012r2-ps).